# Check Characteristic function

Tags: characteristic-functions

How to check whether $\sin(t)\over t$ is a characteristic function or not?

If $\sin(t)\over t$ is a distribution function.

Comment: You could recognise which distribution that it's a characteristic function of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a distribution function because it takes negative values. It is the characteristic function of uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$. Unfortunately, there is no practical way of determining whether a given function is a  characteristic function.